# Arduino for measuring Farads (vs micro/pico farads)

Tags: arduino, supercapacitor

I've been looking for a way to use an arduino to measure capacitance of a supercapacitor that is likely to have a 4F capacitance based on experiments of others.

Several people have experimented with arduino to measure capacitance in the neighborhood of picofarads and microfarads, experimentally demonstrating accuracy of different approaches. [Example1](https://www.circuitbasics.com/how-to-make-an-arduino-capacitance-meter/).

"One meter would accurately measure values in the 1000 μF range, but it would fail in the nF and pF range. Another capacitance meter was accurate in the nF and pF ranges, but failed in the μF range."

Working through a [supercapacitor experiment](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1Ce2au3PWnI&ab_channel=RobertMurray-Smith) with Robert Murray-Smith, I see that the supercapacitor can hold 4 farads.

Has anyone experimented with accurately measuring larger capacitance with an Arduino and, if so, is there a documented approach that I can use as a starting point?

Any pointers are definitely appreciated.

Comment: You provided a link yourself to the kind of "starting point" that you are looking for. Why don't you use that? What is wrong with the approach described there?

Comment: I may have to. I'm hoping to learn from someone else's research if there's someone who has experimentally checked accuracy in the Farad (vs much smaller) ranges.

Comment: It comes down to accurately measuring voltage, current and time, e.g. measuring dV and dt while charging or discharging at constant current. All basics.

Comment: I've designed and build my own battery capacity meter based on an Arduino. It is basically a constant-current discharger that measures the voltage while discharging. The same principle can be used to discharge a Super Cap and determine its capacitance. There are Arduino battery discharger projects to be found if you search for them.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Ah, of course! I didn't think to look into the research around measuring *battery* capacity with arduino & evaluating accuracy. Appreciate the nudge.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I understand the formula, but am interested in what people who have implemented arduino capacitance meters are finding wrt accuracy in the Farad range-- given what Scott Campbell (Example 1) found with smaller capacitance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To measure capacitance requires either measuring (a) impedance versus frequency, or (b) dV/dt versus current.

The problem with measuring pF range capacitors is that of stray capacitances swamping the device under test (DUT). High impedances for (a) or low currents and short times for (b) are difficult to realise. Similarly, but less so, for nF ranges.

μF to mF are generally easy to measure, reasonable impedances, and reasonable currents.

When you get to Farads, you may have problems with the software. Generally only method (b) is used for this range. Some people who make meters for lower ranges may simply not bother providing high enough charging currents, or long enough reading times, to measure this high. There's no fundamental problem, if you wait long enough, but the firmware of particular meters may not allow you to. The maximum capacitance measurement specification will reflect the charging current and the maximum measurement time they've allowed.

Comment: This background does provide helpful insight and perspective regarding accuracy using different approaches. I can't upvote you due to being new and not having enough points. This, combined with @Bimpelrekkie's suggestions should do the trick. Will explore more tomorrow. Thanks!